# In Excel, how do I create a Dynamic Array where each cell is the sum of a corresponding column in another Dynamic Array?

Tags: microsoft-excel

[No VB please.]

## In brief

In Excel, suppose I have a block of numeric data in a Dynamic Array (DA) -- i.e. it is spilling and I don't know (nor want to have to know) the number of rows or columns. I want to sum each column and end up with those sums also being in a DA (spilled).

As an example, consider a simple 4x4 array, rooted at A1:

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I want to end up with the four column sums in a DA rooted at A10, thus:

```
28 32 36 40
```

How do I do that?

## Details

I know that the *meaning* each result cell should have is:

```
A10=SUM(INDEX(A1#,0,1))
B10=SUM(INDEX(A1#,0,2))
C10=SUM(INDEX(A1#,0,3)) and
D10=SUM(INDEX(A1#,0,4))
```

So I've been trying to find a way to get the array {1,2,3,4} into that third argument to INDEX. That's simple if I sacrifice dynamic-ness (dynamism? dynamicosity?...) in the vertical direction. For example:

```
A10=SUM(INDEX($A$1#,0,COLUMNS($A:A)))
B10=SUM(INDEX($A$1#,0,COLUMNS($A:B)))
C10=SUM(INDEX($A$1#,0,COLUMNS($A:C)))
D10=SUM(INDEX($A$1#,0,COLUMNS($A:D)))
```

But as I've said, in practice, I don't know how may rows (or columns) there are, so this all needs to stay dynamic/spillable. So far I've tried various increasingly desperate things, such as:

```
A10=SUM(INDEX(A1#,0,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A1#))))
```

But that gives me a scalar (single cell) answer (the SUM of the first *row* for some reason).

I tried putting that SEQUENCE into a helper row (as a DA), and then used that instead. So if the helper row was rooted at A9, I'd have:

```
A10=SUM(INDEX(A1#,0,A9#))
```

That gives the same result as above. (I guess I should at least be happy that Excel is being consistent in how it doesn't do what I want!)

Comment: Where do you want the result to be placed? In a row which is dynamically determined? Or (like in this example), in a fixed row which is so far below the number block that is is unlikely to collide?

Comment: ... if it is the former: you better forget the "No VB please" comment. In fact, using VBA, the problem is not really hard to solve.

Comment: If your 4x4 array was **not** dynamic (not the result of a formula that spills), you could use a Table structure and just add a Totals row.  The `SUM` function adds everything in the array. So even if you constructed the array properly with arrays `=SUM(INDEX(A1#,SEQUENCE(4),SEQUENCE(,4)))`, that would be equivalent to  `=SUM(A1#)`

Comment: Doc, it's the latter. There is no chance of collision. Re: VBA. The reason I exclude it is I already know how to do it that way. But I prefer to stay in pure Excel when I can, hence my question.

Comment: Ron, the dynamic nature of the initial array is at the heart of the problem. I used a 4x4 just for example, but in practice I won't know the dimensions. I rarely use Tables, but although IIRC they do have some kind of dynamic behavior in that they can handle addition and deletion of rows, they don't have the full dynamic nature of DAs. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

In the event that you re-consider your decision to avoid VBA

In `Sheet1` **A1** I enter:

```
={1,2,3,4,5,6;7,8,9,10,11,99;100,0,0,0,100,0}
```

This makes a nice Dynamic 2-D array:

[image]

Enter the following User Defined Function in a standard module:

```
Public Function foo(r)
    Dim arr, temp, U1 As Long, U2 As Long, i1 As Long, i2 As Long

    arr = Evaluate(r.Formula)
    U1 = UBound(arr, 1)
    U2 = UBound(arr, 2)

    ReDim temp(1 To 1, 1 To UBound(arr, 2))

    For i2 = 1 To U2
        temp(1, i2) = 0
        For i1 = 1 To U1
            temp(1, i2) = temp(1, i2) + arr(i1, i2)
        Next i1
    Next i2

    foo = temp
End Function
```

Then in **A10** enter:

```
=foo(A1)
```

[image]

It does the sums and "spills" across as far as needed.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the comments to my question, the reason I'm saying no VBA is that I can already do it that way if I need to. I'm trying to stick to pure Excel, and in particular the Dynamic Array stuff which I've only recently started using.

Comment: @tkp  I understand.  Good luck with your investigation.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this for sums per column (assuming A1# is the dynamic range with the source data):

=SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A1#,0,SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(A1#))-1,ROWS(A1#),1))

Just change the first argument of the SUBTOTAL function to use any of the aggregation functions available. With some tweaks, this can be made to work for row totals

Answer (score 0):

You can make a general DA formula as follows:

```
=LET( array, A1#,
       ones, SIGN( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( array ) ) ),
       MMULT( ones, array ) )
```

**array** is the range that you want to sum.  I set it to **A1#** to match your example.

There might be a better way to create a series of ones, but this is what came to mind. In any case, the idea is to MMULT a series of **ones** times each Column in the **array**. MMULT then sums up these vertical columns into a DA of equal number of columns.

In this approach, you don't need to know the number of columns or rows in the array. It will adjust to whatever you feed it in **array**.

If you don't have Microsoft 365 and cannot use LET, then you could do:

```
=MMULT( SIGN( SEQUENCE( 1, ROWS( A1# ) ) ), A1# )
```

works the same, but less readable...